# How to track an ID on an email when the user replies?

Tags: php, laravel, email, tracking

I'm using Laravel 5.5. In my app, users can write something and send it through email to someone. The thing they wrote gets recorded as a "message" in my DB. I need to, somehow, send the ID of this message in the e-mail, so when the receiver replies through e-mail, I know which message he's replying to.

What's the easiest way to do this? I know there are APIS, but I need to implement a custom solution.

Thanks for any light on this.

Comment: Add it in the title of the email? `[{$messageId}] Your support request.`

Comment: I agree with @FrankerZ, you can do that, or depending on your email provider (gmail, sendmail, maybe a few others) you may be able to use the plus symbol to append the message ID to your email address and it will still be delivered as if there was no plus symbol and message id in the email address.

Answer (score 0):

Use extended addressing on your mail server - `replies+specialcode@example.com` ... although a lot of bad "email validation" methods think it isn't valid, so I changed the extension character to a hyphen instead of the + on my `postfix` setup.

All mail is delivered to `replies@example.com` but the `to:` and other headers keep the `specialcode` part which you can then use to route into a ticketing system, etc.

This feature is supported by Postfix (`recipient_delimiter` in `main.cf`), QMail, and several other SMTP servers.  Note that you need the support for this on the incoming-to-you SMTP side, nowhere else, especially if you use a character that isn't typically declared as "wrong" by various filters.  May be worth splitting off a subdomain so you can easily set up separate MX servers, etc. since I'm sure you don't want your regular corporate mail running through the same filters and processing (at least, I would...)